# How to sort a dictionary by the value first with asending order, if the value are same the sort the key by desending order

Tags: python

How to sort a dictionary by the value first in descending order, if the value is the same then sort the key in ascending order.

The correct order:

```
[('ipsum', 0.07), ('lorem', 0.07), ('dummy', 0.06), ('type', 0.06), ('typesett', 0.06)]
```

The order of key doesn't correct :

```
[('lorem', 0.07), ('ipsum', 0.07), ('typesett', 0.06), ('type', 0.06), ('dummy', 0.06)]
```

Please use Python.

Comment: What is your current attempt code?

Comment: I don't see any dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a `key` to the `sorted` function that tells it how to sort your dictionary items.  In this case, you want to sort by index 1 of the tuple first.  Since you want it descending order, you can use the fact that it is numeric to flip the ascending order by putting a negative sign on the key.

In the case of a tie, it will sort by the first part of the item tuple, in alphabetical order.

```
d = {'ipsum': 0.07, 'lorem': 0.07, 'dummy': 0.06, 'type': 0.06, 'typesett': 0.06}
sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: (-t[1], t[0]))
# returns:
[('ipsum', 0.07),
 ('lorem', 0.07),
 ('dummy', 0.06),
 ('type', 0.06),
 ('typesett', 0.06)]
```